# Is there fine-grain control over ERD drawing in mysql Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

What I need is to draw ERD of an existing schema/database:

1. Connect to existing db
2. Add some tables as much as I desire dynamically (not all or few upfront as workbench reverse engineering is working currently)
3. Add relationships b/w tables
4. Export ERD

The problem I see is `step 2` where I do not have option to add tables from existing database. What I was expecting was  a drag-and-drop tables option to create ERD diagram from existing database. Please guide me if I am missing some feature.

Comment: When you do reverse engineering you get all tables in the schema tree and can drag them from there to your diagrams. You don't have to add them already during rev eng (there is an option to place objects on a diagram).

Comment: @MikeLischke thanks I explore that option and that is true